# На странице истории правок отсутствует перевод

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, предлагаемые-правки

На странице [истории правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) отсутствует перевод фразы:

> suggested edit on

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Свой перевод лучше дать ответом на свой вопрос. Так удобнее голосовать и предлагать альтернативы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или с парой лишних букв:

> Предложенная правка для

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо! Вы нашли еще одну не переведенную строку в нашем исходном коде.

Я добавил для нее локализацию. Вы можете предложить ваш перевод на [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/91383729?key=029bbed191cf465c41a76413a69109b9).

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю следующий перевод:

> Предложена правка для

Возможно с маленькой буквы как в оригинале.